# IE8 NTLM Ajax no "Content-Length: 0" Post cometD Fiddler

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, ntlm, content-length

I am having an issue where the user logs into NTLM (via localhost:8585/test.ntlm) and the browser attempts to do a handshake through cometD. This works in every single browser except for IE8 ON WinXP (works with IE8 on Win7).

What appears to happen as many have said when IE8 believes it is going through an NTLM page it doesn't send the response body as it expects a 401 error. However the authorization had already happened from when they logged in when prompted to access the /test.ntlm page. I have used Fiddler to actually see the request headers for IE8 and the strange part is that when fiddler is actually on it all works perfectly normal and the request headers that are seen on the server are different from what they are when fiddler is not on.

IE8 WITH Fiddler

```
[Accept][text/javascript, text/html, application/xml, text/xml, */*]
[Accept-Language][en-us]
[x-prototype-version][1.6.0.2]
[Referer][http://nldo-82-2.eur.ad.sag:8585/test.ntlm]
[x-requested-with][XMLHttpRequest]
[Content-Type][application/json; charset=UTF-8]
[Accept-Encoding][gzip, deflate]
[User-Agent][Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.2; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)]
[Host][nldo-82-2.eur.ad.sag:8585]
[Content-Length][0]
[Connection][Keep-Alive]
[Cache-Control][no-cache] -- Only added in IE
[Cookie][JSESSIONID=1ckx2gei602sg]
[Authorization][NTLM TlRMTVNTUAABAAAAB4IIogAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAFAs4OAAAADw==] --Only happens in IE8 when Fiddler isn't on
```

IE8 with Fiddler

```
[Accept][text/javascript, text/html, application/xml, text/xml, */*]
[Accept-Language][en-us]
[x-prototype-version][1.6.0.2]
[Referer][http://nldo-82-2.eur.ad.sag:8585/test.ntlm]
[x-requested-with][XMLHttpRequest]
[Content-Type][application/json; charset=UTF-8]
[Accept-Encoding][gzip, deflate]
[User-Agent][Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.2; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)]
[Host][nldo-82-2.eur.ad.sag:8585]
[Content-Length][177]
[Connection][Keep-Alive]
[Pragma][no-cache]
[Cookie][JSESSIONID=1qpdgov0w07pf]
```

As we can see the biggest difference is that the IE8 w/o Fiddler has the authorization header that is added by the browser as far as I can tell.

I am at a loss of what to do, I have attempted quite a few of the MS hot fixes that are listed in other stackoverflow topics but none of those seemed to work. I attempted to return a 401 as suggested by some as many though the browser was still expecting a 401 to send the response body but that didn't work either. It's just strange that it works perfectly in IE8 for Win7 but not the WinXP version. Note the browser versions are 8.0.7601.17514 for Win7 and 8.0.6001.18702  for WinXP.

Any and all suggestions would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the method to GET and see how it goes?

I've just spent 2 days looking into a problem where ajax POST requests were timing out. All the searching found it was SSO NTLM Authentication issue.

Internet Explorer checks NTLM Authentication on each post request.

Fiddler caches the NTLM Auth and allows requests through withoput a problem.

Comment: Problem with changing to a GET method is that cometd Longpulling only support POST methods.

I had thought Fiddler cached the NTLM auth and that was why it worked properly but that I thought was an option that you had to specifically select when running Fiddler.